# Qt4: Making "Simple Dom Model" editable; inserting rows

Tags: xml, qt, dom, qtreeview

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is combine "Editable Tree Model" and "Simple Dom Model" examples. So I'm having the latter as a base and I've copied the edit functions over there, changed the flags, `setData`, etc.

I've already had success with editing entries.

Now, I have a problem with adding rows to the model.

Specifically, when I use insertAfter function in `QDomNode::parentNode()`, the model gets updated only internally. When I collapse and expand the parent, the added node(s) are copies of the last nodes and are inserted in the end.

The only way I am able to get it right is save XML to `QString` and load it again into `QDomModel` and `QTreeView`. Then everything that has been inserted is where it should be. But then all the expanded states are lost! Not very user-friendly...

---

InsertAfter version:

```
// Get current index
QModelIndex currentTreeIdx = ui->treeView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
// Get the node corresponding to that index
DomItem *itemRef = static_cast(currentTreeIdx.internalPointer());

QDomElement newParentTag;
QDomElement newTextTag;
QDomText newText;
// Create tags
newParentTag = model->domDocument.createElement("Parent");
newTextTag = model->domDocument.createElement("Child");
newText = model->domDocument.createTextNode("Child text data");
newTextTag.appendChild(newText);
newSubtitleTag.appendChild(newTextTag);
// Attempt to insert a new tag after the currently selected item
itemRef->node().parentNode().insertAfter(newParentTag, itemRef->node());
```

---

Now, I've tried adding rows like this instead of `insertAfter`:

```
model->insertRows(itemRef->row(), 1, currentTreeIdx.parent());
```

and the function being called is:

```
bool DomModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent){

    DomItem *parentItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(parent.internalPointer());   // reference item

    bool success;

    beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);
    success = parentItem->insertChildren(position, rows, 4);
    endInsertRows();

    return success;
}
```

This one should create a row. It does create an invisible parent that I can click on to expand. But this parent now contains a copy of the **entire** model...

---

It seems I have a problem with my insertChildren function. As it is now, it replaces the currently selected row with an empty one.

```
bool DomItem::insertChildren(int position, int count, int columns){
    if (position < 0 || position > childItems.size()){
        return false;
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < count; row++){
        DomItem *item = new DomItem(*(new QDomNode()), row, this);   // this doesn't seem to be correct...
        childItems.insert(position, item);
    }

    return true;
}
```